# ошибка Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<IUser[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Делаю сервис со своей логикой, но возникает ошибка ошибка Property 'then' does not exist on  type 'Observable'.

файл сервиса:

```js
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { users } from './home/home.component';
import { IUser } from './IUser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class UserServise {

constructor(private http: Http){}

  public getUsers(){
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(users => {
        return users.map(({id, name, username, email, address, phone, website}) => {
          return {id, name, username, email, address, phone, website}
          });
      });
  }
  public getLinks(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    return Observable.of(users);
  }
  // public getLinksSlowly(): Observable<IUser[]> {
  //   return new Promise(resolve => {
  //     // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
  //     setTimeout(() => resolve(this.getLinks()), 2000);
  //   });
  // }
  public getLink(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.getLinks()
               .then(users => users.find(
                user => user.id === id,
                ));
  }
}
```

файл компоненты:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { UserServise } from '../users.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { users } from '../home/home.component';
import { IUser } from '../IUser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: IUser;
  constructor(
    private userServise: UserServise,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.userServise.getLink(+params.get('id'))
      .subscribe(user => this.user = user));
  }
  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observable` и `Promise` - разные вещи.

Вам нужно подписаться на события:

```
this.getLinks()
  .subscribe(users => ...);
```

Или, если вам нужно использовать их дальше:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

this.getLinks()
  .map(users => ...);
```

Либо, Вы можете применить оператор `toPromise` из `rxjs`:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

this.getLinks()
  .toPromise()
  .then(users => ...);
```

Comment: где именно писать .subscribe(function(data){...});?

Comment: Там, где Вы писали .then

Comment: когда делаю функцию таким образом:

Comment: public getLink(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.getLinks()
      .subscribe(users => users.find(
        user => user.id === id,
      ));
  }

Comment: возникают ошибки:
в сервисе:
Type 'Subscription' is not assigna
ble to type 'Observable<IUser>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
в компоненте: 
Property 'switchMap' d
oes not exist on type 'Observable<ParamMap>'.

Comment: Это уже из другой оперы, проблема решена. Вы не импортировали `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'`

Comment: пробовала так делать, но возникают ошибки:
в сервисе:
Type 'Subscription' is not assigna
ble to type 'Observable<IUser>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
в компоненте:
Argument of type '(pa
rams: ParamMap) => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: Проблема, обозначенная в вопросе решена. Если у вас возникли другие проблемы - не стесняйтесь - создавайте новый вопрос

Comment: @Анна, `then` поменяй на `map`